# Naming sheets and copying data based on cell names

Tags: vba, excel

I have a database created with following information:
Company, worksite, element name, date, number, and few columns with numerical values.

Thing I need is to create a new worksheet (that's easy), with worksheets named after unique company/worksite information (that's the hard part). 
After the sheets are created, I need the whole information regarding each combination from the database to be copied there to respective worksheets (also not sure how to do it).
The worst part is that the company/worksite name is usually longer then 31 characters, so i can't directly use their full names to move within sheets.

Is that even possible ?

I could probably count the unique company/worksite rows, and then copy them whole, while creating a new worksheet for that index. 
But I still have no idea how to deal with the naming.

Edit:
Had some free time on my hands, and decided to work on this.

```
    Sub Zaloz_Arkusze()

    With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Dim wbk3 As Workbook
    Dim wbk4 As Workbook
    Dim LW As Long
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim test As Integer
    Dim Rng As Range, rCell As Range, MyTable As Range, MyTable2 As Range
    i = 1
    j = 4

    'Optimize Macro Speed
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set wbk3 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wbk4 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\rzakrzewski\Desktop\Przeroby.xlsm")

    wbk3.Activate
    Set Rng = Range("A1", Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    LR = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
         Sheets(2).Range("Q1:R" & LR).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets(4).Range("A1"), Unique:=True
    LW = Sheets(4).Range("B1", Sheets(4).Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    Set MyTable = wbk3.Sheets(4).Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
    Set MyTable = wbk3.Sheets(4).Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))

    test = MyTable.Rows.Count

    wbk3.Sheets(2).Activate

    For Each rCell In MyTable
    On Error Resume Next
        wbk4.Activate
        wbk4.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = i
        wbk3.Activate
         With Rng
            .AutoFilter , Field:=18, Criteria1:=rCell.Value
            .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
                wbk4.Sheets(j).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    i = i + 1
    j = j + 1

Next rCell

Application.EnableEvents = True

    End Sub
```

The above sorts data according to company/object name, copies the unique entries and creates a number worksheets in seperate workbook according to number of unique entries. 
I decided to skip the naming part according to company/object. Name length restriction makes this hard to make.

Next part I'm trying to figure out, is to copy data for each unique combination and paste it worksheets. 
Ie. I have unique data combination in Cells B1:C6. I need data in cells D1:T6
copied to second workbook to worksheet(1). 
Have no idea to select the data I require. Any ideas ?

Edit2: As show in above, I tried to work on Autofilter Option.
Problem is, that I need 2 step checking for unique data. Companies have lots of objects under them, and sometimes the same object have a different company. But I've got no idea how to make it work.
Tried a double "For Each" loop, but it's not working.

Comment: Nothing that you described seems particularly hard. You need some sort of abbreviation scheme (and maybe a worksheet which functions as a sort of dictionary with the unabbreviated name in one column and the corresponding abbreviation in the other). You haven't provided enough information to say what the solution is, but it seems straightforward enough. You need to provide more detail and also show what you have tried to do to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After you create a new worksheet you can navigate using:

```
Sheets("NewWorksheetName").Range("A1")="Data"
```